# I am creating a simple program to calculate sales totals involving if/else and keep getting an error message

Tags: c, if-statement

The program calculates discounts (if the customer is a teacher) and sales tax and finds the sales total. I keep getting the error:

> [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SALES_TAX .05
#define DISCOUNT_LOW .10
#define DISCOUNT_HIGH .12
#define DISCOUNT_LIMIT .100

int main(void)
{
    double purchase_total;
    double discount;
    double discounted_total;
    double sales_tax;
    double total;
    int teacher;
    FILE* output_file;

    /* request inputs */
    printf("Is the customer a teacher (y/n)?");
    scanf("%d", &teacher);
    printf("Enter total purchases.");
    scanf("%lf", &purchase_total);

    /* calculations for teacher */
    if (teacher == "y");
    {/*calculate discount (10% or 12%) and 5% sales tax */
        /* purchase total less than 100 */
        if (purchase_total < 100)
        {
            /* calculate 10% discount */
            discount = purchase_total * DISCOUNT_LOW;
            discounted_total = purchase_total - discount;
        }

        /*purchase total greater than 100 */
        else
        {   /* calculate 12% discount */
            discount = purchase_total * DISCOUNT_HIGH;
            discounted_total = purchase_total - discount;
        }

        printf("Total purchases    $%f\n", purchase_total);
        printf("Teacher's discount (12%%)    %fs\n", discount);
        printf("Discounted total     %f\n", discounted_total);
        printf("Sales tax (5%%)    %f\n", sales_tax);
        printf("Total     $%f\n", total);
    }


    /* calculation for nonteacher */
    if (teacher =="n");
    {
        /* calculate only 5% sales tax */
        sales_tax = purchase_total *  sales_tax;
        total = purchase_total + sales_tax;

        printf("Total purchases    $%f\n", purchase_total);
        printf("Sales tax (5%%)    %f\n", sales_tax);
        printf("Total     $%f\n", total);
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Try to use an IDE (maybe eclipse?) or turn on all Warnings of your Compiler. It will warn you on several places. (Like the comparsion in the if or the ; after the if)

Comment: Use `if (something) { `. It will not happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `;` after `if` which is causing the issue

```
if (teacher == "y");
{
```

should be

```
if (teacher == 'y')
{
```

Also

```
if (teacher =="n");
```

should be

```
if (teacher == 'n')
```

One more thing:

```
scanf("%d", &teacher);
```

should be

```
scanf("%c", &teacher);
```

and then note the change of `== "n"` to `== 'n'`

Comment: In addition to fixing the `;`, he should probably do something about the comparison between the integer and the string, too.

Comment: I got rid of the ; after each if but it is still giving me the exact same error messages.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's compiling now.

Comment: Need a bit more help... I'm getting the correct answers for the discount and discounted total, but still getting 0's for the sales tax and total. I'm lost on what to do to fix this now.

Comment: on the RHS, change `sales_tax` to `SALES_TAX`

Comment: You would face the same issue with `sales_tax` in the `if` block too. Ill let you figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's causing your warning:

```
if (teacher == "y")
```

`teacher` is an `int` - `"y"` is a string. You can't compare them.

There are many other problems in your code, including the fact that when you're getting `teacher` in the first place, you're asking for a character, but scanning for an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (teacher == "y");
```

to

```
if (teacher == 'y');
```

and change

```
if (teacher == "n");
```

to

```
if (teacher == 'n');
```

"n" or "y" will be a character array (a string in C). As such its treated like a pointer, which is why you are getting the error you are getting.

Also, when I ran your test program, the comparison to 'y' and 'n' logic worked but I am just getting 0's across the board. You need to fix some logic. I will leave that to you.

Comment: I fixed some things and I'm getting the correct answers for the discount and discounted total, but still getting 0's for the sales tax and total. I'm lost on what to do to fix that...

Comment: Change `sales_tax = purchase_total *  sales_tax;` to `sales_tax = purchase_total *  SALES_TAX;` and please try to understand what you were doing when you wrote your own code, otherwise it's useless. Also, in your code, for teachers, you don't even try to calculate the sales tax, so it's not surprising it'll show as zero in that case. It's more surprising your program doesn't crash from trying to print uninitialized variables.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I just learned how to program a week ago and I am struggling to fully understand it all, so thank you for being patient.